# php array fwrite loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP code here:

```
$info = array();

if($this->build) {
    $info['price_type'] = 'build';
} else if($this->zip) {
    $info['is_co'] = r_check_is_co_zip($this->zip);
    $info['idS'] = r_find_ids_near($this->zip);
    etc etc....
}

$f = fopen(CORE_ROOT . '/../pc/debuging.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, "***ZIPCode DEBUG***" . "\r\n");
fwrite($f, "*date/time: " . date("F j, Y, g:i a") . "*" . "\r\n");
foreach($info as $q) {
    fwrite($f, $q . "\r\n");
}
fwrite($f, "***************************" . "\r\n");
fclose($f);
```

When i try to loop through the array for **$info** i never get anything but **"Array"**. What could i be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Seems like info contains arrays then

Comment: For testing purposes try `foreach($info as $name=>$q) { fwrite($f, $name.'='.var_export($q, true) . "\r\n"); }`

Comment: On an unrelated note, wouldn't it be a better idea to use constants for end of line( PHP_EOL), and directory separator( DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR) since you are doing file manipulations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `print_r($q, true);` or `var_export($q, true);`:

```
$info = array();

if($this->build) {
    $info['price_type'] = 'build';
} else if($this->zip) {
    $info['is_co'] = r_check_is_co_zip($this->zip);
    $info['idS'] = r_find_ids_near($this->zip);
    etc etc....
}

$f = fopen(CORE_ROOT . '/../pc/debuging.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, "***ZIPCode DEBUG***" . "\r\n");
fwrite($f, "*date/time: " . date("F j, Y, g:i a") . "*" . "\r\n");
foreach($info as $q) {
    $toWrite = print_r($q, true);
    fwrite($f, $toWrite . "\r\n");
}
fwrite($f, "***************************" . "\r\n");
fclose($f);
```